Linux: How can I move all files to a subfolder with the first character of the filename?
I have a folder with thousands of files in it. All the filenames start with an alphanumeric character. I would like to create a folder that is the first letter (in uppercase) of each file or if it starts with a numeric into a folder named #. I am looking for some command to do this which I can reuse on other folders.
I have looked into using find and exec but in all honesty my knowledge of linux is pretty limited so I couldn't get it to work.

You would need to write a short shell script that iterates over the files, extracts the initial letter, creates the target directory by running mkdir and then moves the file using mv. Do yourself a favor and don't name a folder # because # is the shell comment character so you'll need to quote it all the time. Using find and exec is a fine solution; maybe you could show us what you've tried so far?

@JonB – Shall it be possible to reuse the command in a directory where it has already been used, after new files have been added?

Are those files to be moved all regular files, or directories also?

with Perl rename: rename '/(.)/; $a = uc$1=~y/0-9/#/r; $_="$a/$_" if -f&&(-d$a||mkdir$a)' [a-zA-Z0-9]*

You could use find and xargs or -exec, but a simple loop should suffice:
for f in *; do
    test -f "$f" || continue
    d="${f:0:1}"
    mkdir -p "$d" || continue
    mv "$f" "$d"
done

Creating a directory named # is a really bad idea, but you could simply add the line case $d in [0-9]) d=\#;; esac if you want to do that.

for f in [a-zA-Z0-9]* and d=${f:0:1}; d=${d^} ?
